# Moving Canvas Arcs Towards Mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

So right now I have a simple canvas element with functions that create random colors, sizes, and positions of arcs (circles).

The 'for' loop that generates the random positions of these random circles executes 1 circle every 100 milliseconds (This is done onclick).

**I want to know how I can make each circle slowly come near the cursor, and then follow the cursor around wherever it moves.**

http://jsfiddle.net/JXXgx/

Comment: Post some code, that we could work with it.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. Here is a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var MAXIMUM_AMOUNT = 1000,
    FPS = 30,
    targetToGo,     //
    shapes = [];    //storage of circles

//Helper class
function CircleModel(x,y,r,color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;   
    this.color = color; 
}
function initScene(){
    //Listening for mouse position changes
    $('canvas').mousemove(function(e){
        targetToGo.x = e.pageX;
        targetToGo.y = e.pageY;
    });
    //Circle generation timer
    var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
        if( shapes.length < MAXIMUM_AMOUNT ){
            for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                //Generating random parameters for circle
                var randX = targetToGo.x - 500 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);   //position x
                var randY = targetToGo.y - 300 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);    //position y
                var randRadius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);       //radius 
                var randColor = "#"+("000000"+(0xFFFFFF*Math.random()).toString(16)).substr(-6); //color
                //Adding circle to scene
                shapes.push( new CircleModel(randX,randY,randRadius,randColor) ); 
            }
        }else{
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    }, 100);
    //Starts rendering timer -  
    //                  '1000' represents 1 second,as FPS represents seconds,not miliseconds
    setInterval(render,1000/FPS);
}
function render(){
    var ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
    var circle;
    //Clearing the scene
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,$('canvas').width(),$('canvas').height());
    //Drawing circles
    for(var i=0; i < shapes.length;++i){
        circle = shapes[i];
        //(animation part)
        //repositioning circle --
        //             (1/circle.r) is a degree of inertion,and the bigger radius,the slower it moves
        circle.x += (targetToGo.x - circle.x)*1/circle.r;   
        circle.y += (targetToGo.y - circle.y)*1/circle.r;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

$("canvas").click(function(e){    
    targetToGo = {x: e.pageX, y:e.pageY};
    initScene();   
});
```

<sub>Put this code inside of `$(document).ready` handler.</sub>

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JXXgx/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is a slick answer. I'll vote it up as soon as I have enough reputation points, haha.

Comment: @Chief120 is this what you want? I have tried to explain my code by comments.I hope you can understand the code.

Comment: Yeah, this is great! If I had to ask for a bit of clarification, it would be on your procedure on getting the randColor, and also maybe a bit of elaboration on 1/circle.r. Thanks.

Comment: @Chief120 About `randColor`,I could say,that if you will be attentive,you will get the logic.It's little hard to explain in words.Just look of docs `toString(radix)` and `slice` functions. The situation is little bit hard with `(1/circle.r)`.I have tried to search in `google` to find the links about basic animation principles,but could not find anything useful.Google is a huge garbage.I'will provide the links and books later.